# Lists:-Why does 1st for loop in the description ends up infinite loop while 2nd for loop works really well

Tags: list, python-3.6

For loop 1

```
li=[]

for i in li:
    li.append(i**2)

print (li)

"""Error...: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-29-c20734da477f>", line 2, in <module>
    li.append(i**2)

KeyboardInterrupt"""
```

For loop 2

```
li=[]

for i in range(0,n):
    li.append(i**2)

print (li)
```

Both should have worked but 1st for loop goes in Infinite loop.Why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first loop doesn't even execute because `li` is empty.

Despite that, in the case that if `li` wasn't empty, e.g `li = [1]`, you are continuously adding elements to it so the `for i in li` will always have elements to iterate through. You are growing the list while going through it.

Using a range, you limit the number of iterations to that specific range. After you iterate through the range of items, the loop stops.

In short, these aren't similar loops.